# How to represent a oneof value that is either a singleton or a collection?

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

Consider the following two valid values of a field in JSON form. `output` field is sometimes a singleton and sometimes a collection.

1)

```
{
    "output": 3.1
}
```

2)

```
{
    "output": [3.1, 4.5]
}
```

Is this representable in proto3 ?

The closest I came is something like this

```
message MyObject {
    oneof output {
       double output_value = 1;
       DoubleArray output_array = 2;
    }
}

message DoubleArray {
    repeated double values = 1; 
}
```

This results in different names in the object and also adds a nesting to the collection value.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, from [GH2592](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2592) it seems like repeated oneofs fields were considered but eventually rejected due to too many complications in implementation.

Creating a wrapper message with repeated field (as you've done) is the canonical workaround for this solution.

```
message MyObject {
    oneof output {
       double value = 1;
       DoubleArray values = 2;
    }
}

message DoubleArray {
    repeated double values = 1;
}
```